# XML Node is not being removed from XML file

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am using org.w3c.dom xml elements.

I get to a point where this line is being called (saw it gets there when debugged the code):

```
node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
```

However, the node remains at the file and it's not being updated at all.

Just for testing, I tried also doing:

```
Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
root.removeChild(node);
node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
```

And then I got an exception on the 3rd line of a null pointer exception, but the node still remains in the file itself, and I can call the deletion action again and the node is found in the file.

Is there something else needed to be done in order to delete the node?

Comment: Please post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. I don't think that `removeChile` is the name of a method at all. And when you remove a node from the DOM tree with `removeChild`, the file is not changed, only the in memory DOM tree, so you would need to save the changed DOM tree back to a file.

Comment: If you are looking for a library where the `Document` object is still live in the file it was loaded from, take a look at JDOM2. It can also do what org.w3c.dom does.

Comment: well Martin if you know that then why won't you write the answer and get an accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very limited. So several possibilities:

1 your are trying to remove a Node you delete before

=> then root.removeChild(node); gives you null at Node

=> then node.getParentNode() throws an exception: why are you doing that ?

2 beware of your search (same problem as above). remove child is recursive. You should think about which paths you remove.

3 you just doesn't save your xml:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Result out = new StreamResult(new File("result.xml"));
Source in = new DOMSource(document);
transformer.transform(in, out);
```

Comment: Too bad the other guys just commented on a mistake I had with "e" and "d" instead of getting the accepted answer like you did